# Singularity of Product of two complex function $f$ and $g$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

> > Suppose $f$ has an essential Singularity at $z = a$ and $g$ has a pole at $z = a$.  Then the product $fg$ has an essential Singularity at $z = a $. Is this hold if $g$ has removable Singularity $ z= a$ or $g$ is analytic at $z = a$

Since $f$ has an essential Singulalty at $z = a$,then  $f$ can be expressed as a laurent Series. i.e $$f(z) = \sum_{i= -\infty}^{\infty} a_i (z-a)^i$$

Suppose $g$ has a ploe of order m, then $g$ can be written as

$$g(z) = \sum_{j = -m }^{\infty} b_j (z-a)^j$$.

Please tell me how to proceed further. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. If you multiply it by a constant function (entire/analytic), or a removable discontinuity, it will remain an essential singularity. You would need to multiply it by something quite extraordinary to be able to get rid of the essential singularity.

Comment: you have taken a particular example. can you explain for any two function, one has essential Singularity and other has a polae at $z = a$.

Comment: Essential singularity means there are poles of infinitely many orders. Obviously, you can't change this situation by raising the order of poles by 1 (multiplying by $1/z$)